# Detecting when jQuery trigger finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('input').trigger('input')
```

when the above function runs, it triggers on all the inputs. How can I tell when all the events that occur as a result of the above action have completed? I think I am asking about the jQuery `when` method, but am not entirely certain....

My effort is:

```
$.when( $('input').trigger('input')).done(
   function (x) {
      if (!$('#mybutton').hasClass('clobbered') {
         submitData();
      }
   }
);
```

*Update:* Thankyou for your comments, it sounds like I was overthinking the problem. I was concerned that trigger may operate asynchronously....

Comment: `$('input').trigger('input')` follows sequential execution... given that none of the handlers does a async process.... if they does we are out of luck as we don't have access to those promises... if there are no async process initiated by the target handlers then the next line will be executed after all the input handlers are fired

Comment: Thankyou, it sounds as if I was thinking too hard ;-P

Comment: it is not possible because `$('input').trigger('input')` return a jQuery object set which was used to call `trigger` so the `done` handler will get executed immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('input').trigger('input')` follows sequential execution... given that none of the handlers does a async process....

If they does have async processes then we are out of luck as we don't have access to those promises...

If there are no async process initiated by the target handlers then the next line will be executed after all the input handlers are fired.

```
$('input').trigger('input')
//do something
```

So in the above case the `do something` part will get called only after all the handlers are called but not necessarily after any async process initiated by those handlers...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will helps you, if I get it right, you try to execute something when some events are actually fired up, right?

So I've made a little experiment as below:

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">

<button type="button">Not yet!</button>
```

```
var numberOfInputs = 5;
var eventCounts = 0;

$(document).on('input', function (e) {
    eventCounts++;    
    if (numberOfInputs === eventCounts) {
        $('button').text('Ready to go!');
    }
});

$('input').trigger('input');
```

It just works.

I assume you know exactly how many `input` you have, but it's ok if not true, you can check the `length` of `$(input)` to make the count right I think.

Comment: I'm not sure your example is correct. I am looking to rely on the trigger event having completed immediately after the statement and was concerned that trigger may operate asynchronously.

Comment: I am confused with your need, "trigger operate asynchronously"? events will never fire off asynchronously, but the callback is.

You trigger a event, others listening to it and execute a callback, this callback will not block sequential codes. You want callback gets invoked only when countable events have been listened, you just make the count. As soon as the condition satisfied, callback will run immediately. I can't see why my code doesn't suit your requirements.

I've put these codes online, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/nightire/4Wng8/, maybe tell us further what you want to archive.